# JQuery Autocomplete for JSON Array

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jsonp

I am trying to use the JQuery Autocomplete on a service which returns a JSON array (in a mimetype application/json).
My development is based on this example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp which retrieves a JSON from the Geonames. The correct json in the geonames example is something like

```
{"totalResultsCount":8387672,"geonames":[{"countryName":"Iran","adminCode1":"23","fclName":"mountain,hill,rock,... ","countryCode":"IR","lng":49.133333,"fcodeName":"mountain","toponymName":"Kūh-e Zardar","fcl":"T","name":"Kūh-e Zardar","fcode":"MT","geonameId":1,"lat":32.983333,"adminName1":"Lorestān","population":0}]}
```

unfortunately my service provides me the following only:

```
["berlin; berlin-steglitz","berliner festspiele"]
```

I am trying to parse the array as well, but even if I get the correct Http 200 and I see the response is correct, I cannot parse the array or work with it. 
The .ajex function "success" from JQuery is not invoked (I suppose because because it expects a json content and retrieves a text) and the "complete" returns me a data object with no method to retrieve the responseText or the content of the Data. 
I cannot use requesttype "text" since the service is in another domain and I break the crossdomain pattern. My code below.

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchinput").autocomplete(
            {
                source : function(request, response) {

                    $.ajax(
                        {
                        url : "http://Mybackendservice.com/",
                        dataType : "jsonp",
                        data : {
                            query : request.term
                        },
                        complete : function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                                console.log(data[i].parametername); /// do whatever you want here.
                            };
                            response($.map(data, function(n,i) {
                                return {
                                    label : n,
                                    value : i
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength : 2,
                select : function(event, ui) {
                    console.log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label
                            : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                },
                open : function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass(
                            "ui-corner-top");
                },
                close : function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass(
                            "ui-corner-all");
                }
            });
});
```

Anyone has some recommendation on how to deal with the problem of parsing such an array?

Comment: What happens when you use `sucess` instead of `complete`? (it should be `success` here). Also are you making a cross-domain request? Otherwise you should not need `jsonp`.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker I mentioned that it does not get into success. And I am using cross-domain request, otherwise I would have just gone for "text"

Comment: Does the `failure` method get executed? If so, does it give you an error message? Also, are you sure the server you're hitting supports JSONP?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Error parseerror [Object, "parsererror", Error]
0: Object
1: "parsererror"
2: Error
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "jQuery18208249744938220829_1364231725702 was not called"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
__proto__: d
callee: function (request,error)
length: 3
__proto__: Object

Comment: Hmm, are you sure the service you're using supports JSONP?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker That is the problem I mentioned. The service I am calling returns me just an array in the form ["berlin; berlin-steglitz","berliner festspiele"] and that is not exactly JSON.

Comment: Actually that is valid JSON (use JSONlint.com to verify). Your service should be prefixing the response with the name of a callback function though.

Comment: Unfortunately do not have access on that back-end service. Any workaround? It looks like I have to write another service within my App that reads JSON through a HTTP call and is invoked by my AJAX request internally.

Comment: You could use a tool like [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) to create a JSONP API, but I would recommend rolling your own in a production scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP requests need the service to prefix the response with the name of the callback function. Some info is provided at the [JSONP page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works)